# Activity function in Durable Function

Tags: azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I'm converting an Azure Function to Durable Function. Currently, I have added one Activity function. Is there any benefit in adding multiple Activity functions instead of one (for instance, cost reduction, less completion time)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have just one Activity function , then I dont see a reason, why you should go for a Durable function. Durable function is meant for operations taking long time which cant be handled due to Timeout issues. with multiple activity, you divide your tasks in multiple function, each taking their time to complete before triggering other